# Incremental/Differential Backup on Windows

Tags: windows, backup, robocopy, xcopy

What's the easiet way to perform an incremental/differential backup to a network share in Windows?

Does a Robocopy/Xcopy solution work reasonably well (I need to the parameters!) or is there a good free tool out there that simplifies the management?

Comment: You should provide more details such as if you want files to be accessible individuals, or can the incrementals be in a single proprietary backup file which you can only access through the backup software.

Answer (score 3):

I use Areca: http://www.areca-backup.org/

It is free and very easy to use. I hope it works for you.

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly the kind of tool I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

How about [SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/prophoto/downloads/synctoybeta.aspx)? It's free and has a nice GUI.

It can easily copy just the changed files to a server.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I use [rsync](http://rsync.samba.org/) on my Mac. If you installed [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com) you would be able to use it.

Answer (score 1):

SyncBack is a great free option for incremental/differential backup.  It has a great GUI and is similar to rsync.  You can download it at CNET.

Answer (score 1):

I was used to Linux stuff, but then for Windows I first tried Duplicity, running through Python under Cygwin, but then with latest versions there were some problems reports.

Then I tried [Duplicati](http://www.duplicati.com/). I've been testing it for some time now including encrypted restores and all seems to work very well – congrats to the developper great simple efficient tool.

Comment: Be careful posting links like this.  While this isn't spam, some community members may incorrectly see it as such.  See the [FAQ#promotion] for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Left field solution. Use Dropbox to sync a folder from the desktop to the server.

Dropbox uses a kind of rsync algorithm to efficiently move data over a LAN, plus for free (up to 2GB) you get an offsite backup.